# How does BitBake make use of variables like B and SRC_URI?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

The following question refers to a plain BitBake setup, i.e., a setup without the classes and configurations that Yocto adds to it.

[BitBake's user manual](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/3.0/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html) describes the variable `B` as follows:

> The directory in which BitBake executes functions during a recipe's build process.

Similarly, `SRC_URI` is described as:

> The list of source files - local or remote. This variable tells BitBake which bits to pull for the build and how to pull them.

After modifying these variables in various scenarios, however, I was unable to notice any difference in the way that BitBake behaves. The working directory that it uses to execute a task, for instance, seems to be the last path of its `dirs` flag.

I know that the `base.bbclass` that is provided as part of Yocto defines `fetch` and `unpack` tasks that make use of the `SRC_URI` variable in the way that the BitBake documentation suggests. Nevertheless, this class is not a part of BitBake.

How do the values of `B`, `SRC_URI`, and similar variables change the behavior of BitBake itself?

Comment: To verify if the changes in the bb files where taken, you can use the -e argument of bitbake to se the value after parsing and how it is build.

Comment: If you clone the bitbake repository you will find lib/bb/fetch2/git.py which implements the git fetcher and other implementation and also the reference to other variables you mentioned. Bitbake handels the metadata. If you are interested how bitbake works without poky I recommend https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#the-hello-world-example